# Launch activity from previous Fragment freezes app

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an app that has a fragment (FragmentMap) with a map and a recycler view. In this fragment if i click on marker or a list item, i can open a new activity to show details of this object.
The problem is: when i press the backbutton inside the DetailAcativity, i come back to the FragmentMap, and if try to open the DetailActivity or any other Activity of my app, it simples freezes and show message "... is not responding".

p.s.: I'm using android annotations lib

I launch the DetailActivity this way:

```
private void selectItem(View view, int position, Place place) {
        String placeJson = new Gson().toJson(place);
        Intent it = new Intent(getActivity(), PlaceDetailActivity_.class);
        it.putExtra(BundleKeys.PLACE_JSON, placeJson);
        if (location != null) {
            it.putExtra(BundleKeys.LATITUDE, location.getLatitude());
            it.putExtra(BundleKeys.LONGITUDE, location.getLongitude());
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Pair<View, String> p1 = new Pair<>(view.findViewById(R.id.iv_image_place), "place_image");
            Pair<View, String> p2 = new Pair<>(view.findViewById(R.id.tv_place_name), "place_name");
            ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions
                    .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(), p1, p2);
            getActivity().startActivity(it, options.toBundle());
        } else {
            getActivity().startActivity(it);
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you post the code of DetailsActivity as well . It helps

Comment: Hi Witalo, did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you connect your real device to the computer and look at the error log and see what is making the app crash, I mean the type of error the log logs. Probably, your fragmentManager failed in the onResume or something. Try connecting your phone to see the error.